# using directive to capitalize input

Tags: angular, directive, angular2-directives, angular5, angular-directive

I have an input I want to capitalize while user writes.

I create a directive to do this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[uppercase]'
})
export class UppercaseDirective {

  constructor() {  }

@Output() outputUpper: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
value: string;

@HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange($event) {
   this.value = $event.target.value.toUpperCase();
   console.log(this.value)
   this.outputUpper.emit(this.value);
}
}

<input matInput (ngModel)="f.value.id" [ngModel]="data?.id" name="id" required placeholder="ID" maxlength="10" uppercase/>
```

I check that the f.value.id is upper, but thats not what I want, I want to change the input value

I can see in console, this.value is correct, but it's not changing in the input. What are I'm missing?

Comment: i guess you must implement ControlValueAccessor of ngModel in this case

Comment: There's is no `ngModel` event. The event is `(ngModelChange)`, which would make it `(ngModelChange)="f.value.id = $event"`

Comment: the event is fired, console shows the upper string, the problem is this is not set in the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, as I was doing it I was changing the value in model but not in input, the solution:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {  }

@HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange($event) {
   this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change [ngModel] with [(ngModel)], two way data binding will do the trick here.

Comment: It crashes because of ? => [ngModel] = data?.id